# Pinescript convert series string to const string

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to create an `alertcondition` having trouble with the `message` argument, my message I want it to contain some of my variable value something like

```
str.format("{0} just broken recent high {1}, new high is {2}", syminfo.ticker, prev_hi, cur_hi)
```

However this will output a series string but `alertcondition` `message` argument expects a const string. I tried to look through the document but cannot seem to find any function to convert a series string to const string.

Is it possible to achieve such behaviour with `alertcondition` or do I have to use `alert`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`series` variables cannot be converted into `const` variables. You need to either use the `alert()` function, which allows for series strings, or to pass your variables to plots and then reference these plots with placeholders as described [here](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000531021).

Comment: thank you very much